# How to use value from HTML form in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I use this part of JavaScript, to define "word" for searching:

```
document.searchform.search_query.value = "word";
```

I want to modify this JS to allow user to add any word from HTML form  to search. I use this HTML form:

```
<form class="input-group navbar-form" id="searchform" name="searchform" action="<?php echo base_url();?>media/search" method="post">
    </li>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Vyhladat titulky..." id="search_query" name="string" />
    </li>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_search"></button>
</form>
```

I tried modify JS in this way, but it doesn't work:

```
document.searchform.search_query.value = document.getElementById("search_query").value;
```

Comment: Try `document.searchform.search_query.value=document.getElementById("search_query").val();`

Comment: @papakia: Nope. That would be wrong.

Comment: @Nikolaus: What doesn't work? And why create code snippets that don't actually do anything. Put together a single working example.

Comment: Can you fix you HTML, right now it's not very good.